# How to pass additional data to serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to add 2 variables in serializer for for calculations in logic serializer

```
serializer = MoviesTopFrameSerializator(topMovie)
```

How can i do this ?
and how to handle inside of serializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***`context`*** to pass [arbitrary data to the serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

```
serializer = MoviesTopFrameSerializator(topMovie, context = {"foo":"bar"})
```

later, this context data can be accessed via the instance attribute as ***`self.context["foo"]`***